# why is it can't load the requirejs module?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZojO.png)

My directory structure is like above,
I linked the script in index.html like
`<script src="lib/requirejs/require.js" data-main="js/app.js"></script>`

And js/app.js is following

```
require.config({
  paths : {
  'backbone' : 'lib/backbone/backbone-min.js',
  'underscore' : 'lib/underscore/underscore-min.js',
  'jquery' : 'lib/jquery/jquery.min.js',
  'bootstrap' : 'lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js',
  },
  shim : {
    bootstrap : {
      deps : 'jquery'
    },

    backbone : {
      deps : ['jquery', 'underscore'],
      exports : 'Backbone'
    },
    underscore : {
      exports : '_'
    }
  }
});

require(['bootstrap'], function (bootstrap) {
  console.log('loaded')
})
```

It can't load the bootstrap.
console's log is `Uncaught Error: Invalid require call`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [in the documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#requireargs) `Invalid require call` is generated when you do a call like:

```
require("foo", function () {...})
```

This is not valid because you should have an array of strings at the first argument. Or if you are using the CommonJS sugar, then you should not have a callback.

There is no `require` call in the code you show that does the above. You'll have to inspect your code base to find the instance of the call that causes the error. You could search through the text of your files. If that proves too difficult, you could change your code to load less and less modules, until the error disappears, then add modules one by one until the error comes back. That would allow narrowing down the set of possibilities.

I've used every library you show in your question, but none of them ever caused the error you report. Either you downloaded a bad build of these libraries or you have custom code elsewhere that causes the error.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem. This error occurs because, In 'bootstrap' key, 'deps' value has to be array of dependencies. not string though module needs to have one module. like `deps : ['jquery']`